# mysql_affected_rows() returns -1

Tags: php, mysql, rows-affected

When executing an SQL statement, such as
    INSERT INTO `table` ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
I rely on mysql_affected_rows() to determine if an insert or an update was performed.
as the mysql site on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-affected-rows.html , it states:

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing row is updated.

All was working Ok until we upgraded to MySQL 5.1.16, when many queries now had mysql_affected_rows() returning MINUS ONE (-1)

The suggested solution on the MySQL site on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysql-store-result.html is to call the function mysql_store_result() after each execution of the function mysql_query() on a select query.

However, PHP does not seem to have such a function defined.

How do I get mysql_affected_rows() to work correctly using PHP and MySQL 5.1.16?

Comment: Are you using prepared statements? By the way, PHP have store_result function - http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php, but store_result is called after SELECTs, not after INSERTs. 

*-1 indicates that the query returned an error or that, for a SELECT query, mysql_affected_rows() was called prior to calling mysql_store_result()*

Comment: I also have this problem...

Answer (score 4):

In general, if `mysql_affected_rows()` returns -1, then it means the query failed (see the [manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php) for more info). You can check what the error was by calling `mysql_error()`, but you should have picked up the error already when you called `mysql_query()` before you get to the point of finding out how many rows were affected.

Since you're asking about the `store_result` function, let me also answer that part of your question:

PHP's `MySQL` module may not have a `store_result` function, but the newer `MySQLi` module does. See http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.store-result.php

It is generally recommended to switch from using the `mysql_xxx` functions to the equivalent `mysqli_xxx` functions anyway, so this would be a perfect opportunity for you to do so.

You don't need to upgrade your PHP version for this, as the MySQLi module was introduced with PHP 5.0. However I would suggest considering an upgrade nonetheless -- if you're using PHP 5.1, you are using a version which has been out of support for over five years already.

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_affected_rows` returns -1 if the last query failed.  I would check your queries and/or database connection.  See [this link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-affected-rows.php).